# Trying to set a new font, and I get: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Tags: vb.net

You guys have been a great help getting me back up to speed after a 7-year retirement from programming.

I am trying to change the font in a sub that draws text in a graphic object.  Here's my code:

```
Private Sub AddLine(ByVal text As String, ByVal Font_name As String, ByVal Font_Size As Integer, ByRef yPosition As Integer, ByVal Alignment As Integer, ByVal G As Graphics, ByVal B As SolidBrush, ByVal ScreenWidth As Integer)
    Try
        Dim F As New Font(Font_name, Font_Size)
```

The error shows when I hover over "F" in the dim statement at runtime.  (There's a breakpoint on the next line).

Ironically, the program works in spite of the error, but I like to keep my code clean.  I've spent the day trying various suggestions on the forum, but nothing works.  any ideas of how I should code this New Font line would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a bug in the debugger, not in your code.  It complains about the "Name" property but when you expand the dropdown (click on the triangle) then you'll see that Name actually has a value.  Don't lose any sleep over this.  You can tell Microsoft about it at connect.microsoft.com if you like.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), when you declare a new Font, you should use the Font Size as Single and not as Integer, thus, you get an error although the code works fine. Try to change the parameter Font_Size from Integer to Single.